# Как передать через Ajax многострочный параметр

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Третий день бьюсь с проблемой передачи многострочного параметра через Ajax+JQuery

```
HTML
<textarea id="test"></textarea> //пробовал DIV

JS
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/ajax",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        data: ds,
          complete: function(resp) {
            rs = resp.responseJSON;
            var dopParams = rs.dop; //массив выражений JQuery
            if (dopParams !== undefined) {
              for (i = 0; i < dopParams.length; i++) {
                console.log((dopParams[i]))
                eval(dopParams[i]);
}
}
```

PHP
получаю такой массив и хотел бы в таком же виде отобразить

```
Array
(
    [keys] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [dongle_id] => 1065510441
                    [prog_ver] => 16778245
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [dongle_id] => 1065509103
                    [prog_ver] => 16778249
                )
            )

    [type] => keys_list
)
```

PHP->JS в конце концов возвращаю результат Ajax запроса

```
  $test = nl2br($array); // последние изыскания, без этих команд тоже пробовал
  $test = str_replace("\n", "", $test);
  $dop[] = '$("#responseQ").html("' .$test .'")';
$response = [
    'switch' => $switch,
    'dop' => $dop,
  ];


   echo json_encode($response);
```

Если ответ сформировать в одну строку без форматирования, то работает, но смотреть таким образом массив сложно.

Comment: смотреть таким образом что? .... и почему бы не выводить данные через `pre`?

Comment: нажатие кнопки посылки запроса вызывает ajax запрос (без перезагрузки страницы). Согласно ему я формирую запрос в сторону некого сервера с подключенными key-токенами. Полученный ответ возвращаю в определенное место на экране. Смотреть хочу ответы сервера на команды. На приведенном примере я запросил список подключенных ключей, получил и хочу показать самому себе что именно получил - массив из таких-то элементов. На счет pre уточните.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому пригодится. Многострочный текст через ajx/jquery смог передать используя метод .appendTo (дополняю div построчно) и массив из jq команд:

```
$dop[] = "$('Вставай проклятьем заклейменный').appendTo('#div_output')";
$dop[] = "$('Весь мир голодных и рабов').appendTo('#div_output')";
```

Правда временно сохраняю значение переменной в файл, а потом построчно считываю. Зато плюс- всегда можно посмотреть что отправлял.

```
file_put_contents("file_name",print_r($my_var,true));
$dop[] = "$('#div_output').empty()";
$fd = fopen("file_name", 'r');
    $PCREpattern  =  '/\r\n|\r|\n/u'; //удаляю переносы строк
    while(!feof($fd)){
      $row = fgets($fd);
      $str = preg_replace($PCREpattern, '', $row);
      $str = str_replace(" ", "&nbsp;", $str); //заменяю пробелы
      $dop[] = '$("$str").appendTo("#div_output")';
    }
    fclose($fd);
```

Answer (score 0):

нужно сделать чуть по-другому:

1. С сервера ожидать просто текст
2. На сервере сформировать данные таким образом:

   ```
   ob_start();
   echo '<pre>';
   var_dump($data);
   echo '</pre>';
   $result = ob_get_clean();

   echo $result; // возвращаем строку с данными
   ```

на js будет просто

```
$("#test").html(response);
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137852/discussion-on-answer-by------ajax-).